# Use Moment.js to convert human readable time to Unix epoch time

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, unix-timestamp, epoch

I'm trying to use Moment.js to convert a human readable time to a Unix epoch time. I'd also like to know.

`35 MIN AGO` to `Unix epoch time`

Comment: I don't think there is such a function in moment.js, because it would be idiotic ... I mean ... the string generated in the moment expires like after a minute, so converting it back to timestamp doesn't make any sense; you can write your own parser based on this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSUQv.png, but still ... seems to be a bit stupid

Comment: `moment().unix()`....

Answer (score 0):

`.unix()` method returns unix timestamp if thats what you are looking for.

For conversions you would have to specify what does it means human readable time.

35 min ago would look somehing like this;
`moment().subtract(35, 'minutes').unix()`